# CMake can't find OpenMP on `manylinux` images, even though it is installed

Tags: cmake, openmp, python-manylinux

During a `cibuildwheel --platform linux` build using `scikit-build` on the `quay.io/pypa/manylinux2014_x86_64` image CMake 3.27 cannot find `OpenMP`:

```
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES) 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FOUND) (found version "4.5")
```

I find it a bit of a strange log since it finds `OpenMP_C`, but not `OpenMP` .. but does find version "4.5"?

The `libgomp` package is installed, and the files are picked up by ldconfig:

```
sh-4.2# ldconfig -p | grep gomp
        libgomp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgomp.so.1
```